# Flutter default image not loading

Tags: flutter

New to flutter. Working on a personal project. Stuck with a small issue related to show images. Here is my widget code which I'm using for showing images.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  UserProfileState createState() => new UserProfileState();
}

class UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {

  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Map userDetails = {};
  String profileImgPath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDetails();
  }


  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    try {
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
      this.userDetails = json.decode(prefs.getString('user'));

      if (prefs.getString('user') != null) {
        if (this.userDetails['isLoggedIn']) {
          setState(() {
            this.profileImgPath = this.userDetails['profileImg'];
            print('Shared preference userDetailsss : ${this.userDetails}');
          });
        }
      } else {
        print('Shared preference has no data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception caught at getUserDetails method');
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget profileImage = new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: (this.profileImgPath == null) ? new AssetImage('images/user-avatar.png') : new CachedNetworkImageProvider(this.profileImgPath),
                radius:50.0,
              )
            ],
          )
        )
        ],
      )
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Profile"), backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF009688)),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          profileImage,
        ],
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, show the default `user-avatar.png` image as long as `CachedNetworkImageProvider` don't get original image. But, it's bit behaving differently.

Whenever I'm opening the page - I'm getting a blank blue box then suddenly the original image from `CachedNetworkImageProvider` comes up.

[image]

Can't able to understand what's happening.

---

@Jonah Williams for your reference -
[image]

Answer (score 6):

`CachedNetworkImage` can't be used for `backgroundImage` property because it does not extends `ImageProvider`. You can create a custom `CircleAvatar` like described below to use the `CachedNetworkImage` package:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomCircleAvatar extends StatelessWidget {

  final int animationDuration;
  final double radius;
  final String imagePath;

  const CustomCircleAvatar({
    Key key, 
    this.animationDuration, 
    this.radius, 
    this.imagePath
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      duration: new Duration(
        milliseconds: animationDuration,
      ),
      constraints: new BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: radius,
        maxHeight: radius,
        minWidth: radius,
        maxWidth: radius,
      ),
      child: new ClipOval(
        child: new CachedNetworkImage(
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          imageUrl: imagePath,
          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

And how to use:

```
body: new Center(
        child: new CustomCircleAvatar(
          animationDuration: 300,
          radius: 100.0,
          imagePath: 'https://avatars-01.gitter.im/g/u/mi6friend4all_twitter?s=128',
        ),
      ),
```

Maybe it is not the better way. But, it works!

Comment: `CachedNetworkImage` also provides an `imageBuilder` that you can use to create a custom image avoiding all this process. E.g: `imageBuilder: (_, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: imageProvider,
        radius: 20,
      )`

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that CachedNetworkImageProvider is actually CachedNetworkImage from [this](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/blob/master/lib/cached_network_image.dart) package).

This line of code will always display the second image.

```
(this.profileImgPath == null)
  ? new AssetImage('images/user-avatar.png')
  : new CachedNetworkImageProvider(this.profileImgPath)
```

Since profileImagePath is not null, the AssetImage is never created.  Even if it was, as soon as it's not the cached network image will replace it before it has loaded.  Instead, use the `placeholder` parameter of the network image.  This will display your asset image until the network image loads.

```
new CachedNetworkImage(
  placeholder: new AssetImage('images/user-avatar.png'),
  imageUrl: profileImgPath,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried ```CachedNetworkImage()``` also. But, whenever I was trying that I was getting this error ```The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider. ```

Comment: Included a screenshot of the error in the main the bottom of the post for reference.

Comment: ahh I see now, ignore my answer this is what I get for doing things late at night

Comment: No problems. Same happens with me after 6PM :D